# Sum of multiple rows using different cases

Tags: mysql

In my table for payment details of a shop.Here Payment is done by using credit,debit and by cash.This will represent in the table like a field "mode"
If mode=1 cash,mode=2 credit and mode=3 debit.

Now i take the daily fee details using this query

```
 SELECT * FROM (`fee_data`) WHERE `paid_date` =  '2015-20-11'
```

I want to get the sum of Paid amount in different modes

How can i do  this..

Comment: You'll need to add more details on your database structure (for example, what's the name of the field with the fee amount?) and what you wish as a result if you want a precise answer. The imprecise answer is using `SUM` and `GROUP BY` to get a sum by mode.

Comment: What columns are in the fee_data table? Which do you need to output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use sum(if( in combination with grouping by date, something like this:

```
SELECT `paid_date`, sum(if(mode=1, `fee_data`, 0)) sumMode1,
sum(if(mode=2, `fee_data`, 0)) sumMode2,
sum(if(mode=2, `fee_data`, 0)) sumMode3
FROM (`fee_data`) group by `paid_date`
```

With that you will get per date one line, where you have 3 aggregated columns. For each mode you have one aggregated field. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
SET @paid_date = '2015-01-19 00:00:00';

SELECT 
SUM (CASE WHEN MODE = 1 THEN VALUE_PAYMENT ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_1,
SUM (CASE WHEN MODE = 2 THEN VALUE_PAYMENT ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_2,
SUM (CASE WHEN MODE = 3 THEN VALUE_PAYMENT ELSE 0 END) TOTAL_3
FROM (`fee_data`) WHERE `paid_date` =  @paid_date;
```

Where value_payment is the column you store the amount paid.

Comment: In my where condition is like this

Comment: if($date =="")
          {
                $this->db->where('paid_date',date("Y-m-d"));
          }
          else
          {
               $this->db->where('paid_date',$date); 
          }

Comment: Does it works? What is the problem with your where clause?

Comment: Ok. This is better: if($date =="") { $date = date("Y-m-d");}  $this->db->where('paid_date',$date);

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```
SELECT * FROM (`fee_data`) WHERE `paid_date` =  '2015-20-11' AND ModeID=1
```

make changes in DB tables accordingly

Comment: That sounds like what they've got already - how does that help? It only shows the output for one mode type, are you suggesting they run three queries instead of one?

Comment: Set ModeID value  dynamically.   set  @modeID= **

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *, SUM(paid_amount) as sum_amount FROM (`fee_data`) WHERE `paid_date` =  '2015-20-11' GROUP BY mode

I think this should work

Comment: It won't work unless `mode` and `paid_amount` are the only columns in the table, because of the asterisk - other columns would need to be excluded from the select, or included in the group by statement. I've asked OP to clarify this in the question.